# Can I tell Make to ignore environment variables?

Tags: bash, makefile

I came across some odd behavior when using Make recently (v3.81).

Suppose I have the following Makefile:

```
FOOBAR = $(shell find nonexistentdirectory -iname "foobar" | tr '\n' ' ')

all:
    @echo "Hi"

clean:
    @echo "Hi again"
```

Seems straightforward enough, right?  Notably, `FOOBAR` is a "recursively-expanded variable", so it should not be evaluated until I refer to it.  Note that I never refer to it.  Also note that `nonexistentdirectory` does not exist as you might expect.

Now suppose I set `FOOBAR` *in the shell* before I invoke a Make target:

```
compy386$ FOOBAR="stuff" make clean
find: nonexistentdirectory: No such file or directory
Hi again
```

Why is `FOOBAR` being evaluated?  Clearly it has something to do with the fact that the variable is defined in the shell.  Am I supposed to anticipate that a user *might have set* variables in their shell?  What am I doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FOOBAR` is being evaluated because you are running a recipe (for `clean`) and `FOOBAR` existed in the environment on entry to `make`. Because `FOOBAR` existed in the environment on entry, it becomes an exported variable, which means that `make` will provide it as part of the environment to any program in the recipe. `make` doesn't special-case `echo`; it just uses the one found in your path. And it can't know whether or not that utility will reference a particular environment variable, so it has to export all exported variables, which means it has to evaluate `FOOBAR`.

(For the official word, see the third paragraph of [Variables from the Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) in the make manual. Also see the recipe on [recursive make invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion).)

To answer the direct question, you can tell `make` to ignore the fact that a variable came from the environment, so that it doesn't re-export it, by unexporting it:

```
unexport FOOBAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `?` before the `=` like:

```
FOOBAR ?= $(shell find nonexistentdirectory -iname "foobar" | tr '\n' ' ')
```

This will use the environment variable if set and only evaluate if unset or empty.